# R - How to re-order row index number

Tags: r, vector, indexing, dataframe, row

Simply put, I have the following data frame:

```
        Signal
    4   9998
    3   549
    1   18
    5   2.342
    2   0.043
```

and I want to reset the index numbers to be like :

```
        Signal
    1   9998
    2   549
    3   18
    4   2.342
    5   0.043
```

Comment: Try `yourdf <- yourdf[order(-yourdf$Signal),, drop=FALSE];row.names(yourdf) <- NULL`

Comment: @akrun, Thank you for your comment. To reset the index number, part of  your code : 'row.names(yourdf) <- NULL'  was the answer, would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use

```
 row.names(yourdf) <- NULL
```

to reset the row names